# How to add extra summary_field in Silverstripe when extending an object?

Tags: php, oop, silverstripe

I'm wanting to extend an existing Silverstripe module (Swipestripe) where Attribute has_many Options.

The following code successfully extends Option so a Cost is added to each Option.

```
class OptionCost extends DataExtension {

  private static $db = array(
      'Cost' => 'Decimal(19,4)'
  );

  public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new PriceField('Cost'));
    return $fields;
  }
}
```

However when viewing the options via the parent Attribute the Cost is not display. This is controlled via the **$summary_fields** static but I can't work how to add Cost as a new summary field.

I've tried adding the following code to OptionCost, and to an extension of Attribute - but neither method worked.

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
  'Cost' => 'Cost'
);
```

What is the correct approach to add Cost to the summary_fields table?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Silverstripe 3.1 adding fields to `$summary_fields` in the extension is the correct way to do this.

The following code worked for me:

```php
class OptionCost extends DataExtension  {

    private static $db = array(
        'Cost' => 'Decimal(19,4)'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Cost'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new PriceField('Cost'));
        return $fields;
    }

}
```

Declare the extension in your config or in a config yaml file.

**config.yml**

```
...
Attribute:
  extensions:
    - OptionCost
...
```

Run a `dev/build?flush=all`.

Also make sure you call `?flush=all` on your admin page.

Comment: Thank you @3dgoo - it was the ?flush=all I was missing. I extended Option rather than Attribute and it worked with the $summary_fields. Another thing I discovered is extending $summary_fields overwrites rather than appends. Thanks again.

Comment: If ever in doubt, flush. `$summary_fields` appends if the original class has it's own declaration of `$summary_fields`. `Attribute` has a `$summary_fields`. If you were to extend `Attribute` it would append the `$summary_fields`. `Option` does not have a `$summary_fields` declared. So it uses the fields you have set in your extension's `$summary_fields`.